# How do I implement a goBack function in app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I have three html pages on app script, respectively index.html second.html and third.html. I am trying to implement a goBack function that returns me back from the second page or another page to the home page. I tried windwo.history.back but it did not work. Does anyone know how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

Add a button widget on the UI and on the onClick event handler add the following:

```
app.showPage(app.pages.yourHomePage);
```

See the the image below:

[image]

Comment: Hmm this is a good solution, but only for appmaker. I need it for Google Apps Script

Comment: `windows.history.back()` is your friend, but unfortunately it works only in Firefox and Chrome older then v63 (approximately). I think there is an Apps Script bug/feature request to address it.